# django, property update a model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

```
1. instance.save()

2. instance.foo = foo; instance.save(update_fields=['foo'])

3. InstanceClass.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(foo=foo)
```

I found that #3 is sometimes not reliable.
after I run #3, occasionally foo is not properly set (not commited?)

I used to use #3 when I don't want to run signal handlers.

When to use each of the above 3?

Answer (score 6):

If you’re just updating a record and don’t need to do anything with the model object, the most efficient approach is to call `update()`, rather than loading the model object into memory. For example, instead of doing this:

```
instance = Entry.objects.get(id=10)
instance.comments_on = False
instance.save()
```

do this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(id=10).update(comments_on=False)
```

**NB :**

1. Using `update()` also prevents a race condition wherein something might change in your database in the short period of time between loading the object and calling `save().`*
2. `update()` does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any `save()`, so if you have an overrided **save()** method you have to use the first way with `get()` and `save()`.

Check the [Queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update) documentation, it's all explained here.